# Convert numpy.array object to PIL image object

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to convert a numpy array to PIL image using Image.fromarray but it shows the following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Shri1008 Saurav
>   Das\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py",
>   line 2428, in fromarray
>       mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey] KeyError: ((1, 1, 3062), '|u1')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Shri1008 Saurav
>   Das/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/projects/try.py", line
>   13, in 
>       img = Image.fromarray(IMIR)   File "C:\Users\Shri1008 Saurav Das\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py",
>   line 2431, in fromarray
>       raise TypeError("Cannot handle this data type") TypeError: Cannot handle this data type

I extracted the matrix from an hdf5 file and converted it to a numpy array. I then did some basic transformations to enhance contrast(most probable reason for error). Here is the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
import h5py as hp
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

hf = hp.File('3RIMG_13JUL2018_0015_L1C_SGP.h5', 'r')
IMIR = hf.get('IMG_MIR')
IMIR = np.uint8(np.power(np.double(np.array(IMIR)),4)/5000000000)
IMIR = np.array(IMIR)

root = tk.Tk()
img = Image.fromarray(IMIR)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = img)
cv = tk.Canvas(root, width=photo.width(), height=photo.height())
cv.create_image(1,1,anchor="nw",image=photo)
```

I am running Python 3.6 on Windows 10. Please help.

Comment: PIL requires MxN(x3) arrays of a reasonable data type. What are you passing in?

Comment: Its a M*N*1 Matrix (hence grayscale) and I have toned it down(using /5000000000) to 0-255 limits, suitable for uint8 type

Comment: Here's the dset if it helps [**DATASET LINK**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UX8GyztY1OWgQIQbFUhl8lO4CH-7-ZjW/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the shape of your data. Pillow's `fromarray` function can only do a MxNx3 array (RGB image), or an MxN array (grayscale). To make the grayscale image work, you have to turn you MxNx1 array into a MxN array. You can do this by using the `np.reshape()` function. This will flatten out the data and then put it into a different array shape.

`IMIR = IMIR.reshape(M, N) #let M and N be the dimensions of your image`

(add this before the `img = Image.fromarray(IMIR)`)