# KeyError: ((1, 1, 1280), '|u1') while using PIL's Image.fromarray - PIL

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, pixel

I have this code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('img.jpg')
Image.fromarray(np.array([[np.mean(i, axis=1).astype(int).tolist()]*len(i) for i in np.array(img).tolist()]).astype('uint8')).show()
```

And I am trying to modify the pixels of the image in PIL, however when I run it it gives an error as follows:

```
KeyError: ((1, 1, 1280), '|u1')
```

Not just that, it also outputs a second error as follows:

```
TypeError: Cannot handle this data type
```

Is there a way to overcome this?

P.S. I searched and the most related question to mine was:

[Convert numpy.array object to PIL image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479140/convert-numpy-array-object-to-pil-image-object)

However I don't get it nor know how to implement it.

Comment: I can't read your code, there are far too many steps in one line. Try shorter lines - it's easier to debug. In what way do you want to modify the pixels?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Ugh i am addicted to ugly code :P

Comment: In what way do you want to modify the pixels? Are you adding 1 to each? Or averaging something? I am sure there is a miles easier solution if I know what you want to do!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am averaging the pixels

Answer (score 3):

For reading specific pixel via any image library such as `PIL` or `OpenCV` first channel of image is **Height** second channel is **Width** and last one is **number of channels** and here is `3`. When you convert image to gray scale, third channel will be `1`.

But this error happen when you want to convert a numpy array to PIL image using `Image.fromarray` but it shows the following error:

```
KeyError: ((1, 1, 3062), '|u1')
```

Here you could see another solution:
[Convert numpy.array object to PIL image object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51479140/convert-numpy-array-object-to-pil-image-object)

**the shape of your data**. 
Pillow's `fromarray` function can only do a MxNx3 array (RGB image), or an MxN array (grayscale). To make the grayscale image work, you have to turn you MxNx1 array into a MxN array. You can do this by using the `np.reshape()` function. This will flatten out the data and then put it into a different array shape.

```
img = img.reshape(M, N) #let M and N be the dimensions of your image
```

(add this before the `img = Image.fromarray(img)`)

Comment: Height first or width first?

Comment: So if 1920x1020 `M` will be `1020` and `N` will be `1920`?

Comment: In PIL height is the first and width is the second. I wrote answer based on https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom/issues/48#issuecomment-289331878 and height, width = np.array(im).shape and https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34704661/revisions and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444548/how-do-i-get-the-picture-size-with-pil/6444612

Comment: @U10-Forward Absolutely when  you write 1920*1020, 1920 is width and 1020 is height. But what dimension PIL give us when you call it? So function return (1020,1920) so 1020 is height and 1920 is width

Comment: Lemme try will give you feedback soon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198356/discussion-between-u10-forward-and-barzanhayati).

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain what you are trying to do but if you want the mean:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('img.jpg')

# Make Numpy array
imgN = np.array(img)

mean = np.mean(imgN,axis=2)

# Revert back to PIL Image from Numpy array
result = Image.fromarray(mean)
```

Alternatively, if you want a greyscale which is an alternative to the mean

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('img.jpg').convert('L')
```

Comment: Amm that's not what i want