# Cannot handle this data type: (1, 1, 1), |u1

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I already have a trained model for reflection removal; but whenever loaded it outputed this error. While I ensure the input image is in the appropraite dimension of 128 x 128 and .png format.

```
# Define the input shape (assuming grayscale images of size 128x128)
input_shape = (128, 128, 1)
input_images_dir = 'input'
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
for filename in os.listdir(input_images_dir):
    if filename.endswith('.png'):
        image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(os.path.join(input_images_dir, filename), target_size=input_shape[:2], color_mode='grayscale')
        input_image = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(image) / 255.0
        reflection_free_image = remove_reflections(np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0), generator)[0]

        # Calculate PSNR and SSIM between original input image and reflection-free image
        psnr_value = psnr(np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0), reflection_free_image)
        ssim_value = ssim(np.expand_dims(input_image, axis=0), reflection_free_image)

        # Annotate the reflection-free image with PSNR and SSIM values   
        annotated_image = annotate_image_with_metrics(Image.fromarray((reflection_free_image * 255).astype(np.uint8))
```

```
  File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py:3070 in fromarray
    mode, rawmode = _fromarray_typemap[typekey]

KeyError: ((1, 1, 1), '|u1')
```

I have included my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [KeyError: ((1, 1, 1280), '|u1') while using PIL's Image.fromarray - PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621092/keyerror-1-1-1280-u1-while-using-pils-image-fromarray-pil)

Comment: @david not really!